# Open a new window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know this is simple and a dumb question but I can't for the life of me make this work for some reason...

So I have a link (based on a non-angular popup using onclick):

```
<a href="page.html" ng-click="popitup('page.html')">Page</a>
```

And a function within the scope:

```
$scope.popitup = function(url) {
  return $window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=200,width=150');
};
```

All I want is, when someone clicks the link, open a new window and display page.html. I have tried changing small parts of the link and the function, but I can't get it. I'm sure it's something small I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you passing in $scope and $window in your controller function like in the docs example? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: AH! That might be it.. brb compiling..

Comment: Nevermind. I added $window and $scope was already there. Didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Try assigning a reference to the method's return value. It may help you debug. var newWin = $window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=200,width=150'); Then log/dir the newWin var

Comment: Oh and try using a fully qualified url for page.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. In HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a  role="link" ng-click="popitup('page.html', '_blank')">Page</a>
  </body>
```

In controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.popitup = function(url, target) {
  $window.open(url, target);
};
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fChBoVZ5UWHRnDr6Nqh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

html

```
 <a data-ng-click="openPrintMode()">
                            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                        </a>
```

controller

```
$rootScope.openPrintMode = openPrintMode;

function openPrintMode() {
            $window.open($location.$$absUrl + "?v=p", "_blank");
        }
```